# Rapidoid rest dependency while trying to use "On"

Tags: rapidoid

I'm having trouble while trying to create a simple maven based project with rapidoid-rest as dependency.

I just have a single dependency in my pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.rapidoid</groupId>
            <artifactId>rapidoid-rest</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And the main app code is like this

```
On.get("/example").json("example")
```

`On` is a class coming from rapidoid-http-server dependency and should be included in rapidoid-rest. It seems like it is only included with "test" as scope. If I add it as a new dependency, I'm getting a version mismatch as one is 5.0.12 while the other is 5.5.4. I'm even unable to run examples from github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the rapidoid-http-server module. Recently it was renamed to rapidoid-rest for the upcoming v6 release.